# 'Varien Autoload' error

Tags: magento-1, varien-autoload

In setting up a copy of the Magento site on a new server, when I try to view the website I get this message:

> Array
> (
> [type] => 1
> [message] => Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found
> [file] => /home/matthewbutterwor/public_html/app/Mage.php
> [line] => 54
> )

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Check Compilation mode is disabled or not in include/config.php file.
If that not then edit and make two lines like written below.

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Clear the cache and then check.

Comment: Correction: error is now '500 Internal Server Error'.

Comment: That means your old issues resolved, now new issue comes.

Comment: Have you check in private browser?

Comment: I have manipulated my ip configuration in order to view website on server, and I have also tried via hosts.cx.  Issue remains unresolved.